# how to convert date format from 01-04-2014 to Jan 4?

Tags: php, date

I have date list. I want `01-04-2014` show as `Jan 4` and `01-05-2014` show as `Jan 5`. How do i do this? Here is my code:

```
$dates = array();
$timestamp = strtotime('-30 days');
for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {

    //insert the date
    $dates[$i]= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);

    //increase the day
    $timestamp += 24 * 3600;
}
```

First i want to get dates then convert after for loop.

Comment: Read the `date` manual, it is all in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) objects:

```
$str = '01-04-2014';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
echo $dateObj->format('M d');
```

Output:

```
Jan 04
```

**Explanation:**

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) allows you to parse a date string of *any* format and create a DateTime object
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method is used to format the date to the desired format

For a list of other available formatting options, see the [documentation for `date()`](http://php.net/date).

Comment: Note: `DateTime::createFromFormat()` will not work in php<5.2.1

Comment: Note: True. Although: anything before PHP 5.3.0 is *ancient*. You should **upgrade** to a modern PHP version. Also, the DateTime class has some really cool features and works on a wider range of dates (that strtotime() and date() can't handle on 32-bit systems).

Comment: I just left the note for helping purpose.I accept your point too.

Answer (score 2):

[`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can do that all for you:

```
echo date("M j", $timestamp);
```

It has many more formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$dates = array();
$timestamp = strtotime('-30 days');
for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
   $dates[$i]= date('M j', $timestamp);
   $timestamp += 24 * 3600;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date = new DateTime('01-04-2014');
echo $date->format('d,M H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.It works in all PHP versions

```
$input = '01-04-2014';
$a = explode('-',$input);
$result = strftime("%b",mktime(0,0,0,$a[0])).''.intval($a[1]); 
echo $result;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/80MTp)